# How to get the no of attachments in an email using objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Hi am new to xcode programing,i am trying an app regarding the email attachments to show the no of attachments an email contains,i got the single attachment showing but i need how n=many are there in particular email,if any body knows about this please help me.Here is the code regarding the app:

Comment: You have to supply _a lot_ more information, e.g. how are you accessing the emails exactly, is this in an official or jailbroken environment etc. etc.

Comment: by using imap server am accessing the emails.

Comment: Still more details needed. Are you using some IMAP library? If so which one? Have you done your own implementation? If so, this is more about how this information is encoded in the raw email.

Comment: yes am using the imap.gmail.com server.no its not my own implementation by seeing the example app in mailcore i tried it.am getting the individual attachments but what i need is if an email contains more than 2 attachments how to get it.

Comment: I suppose its the mailcore project on github? Better put in some links /info in your original posting and some code how you go about, too. Not everyone knows this framework by heart but may still be able to help you when seeing some of it is use.

Answer (score 1):

From looking solely at the code you have provided, it would appear that all you need is `[attachments count]` to provide the number of attachments in the current message